# Transposition table makes algorithm slower (am I doing it wrong?)

Tags: c++, chess

I store every position with a Zobrist key (64-bit). I store theses in a std::vector. At the beginning I std::vector::reserve(1,000,000). When a position is searched, it takes a long time to check if the key is in the vector, and if it is, a long time to locate it.

This happens at later depths when the vector of transpositions becomes so long it's faster just to re-compute the position instead of looking for a transposition.

What I've tried:

-inserting the keys into the vector sorted from least to greatest and using a binary search to locate them later.

-pushing the key to the vector, and every time I want to check for a key, looping through the vector to check for a matching key.

Also in case it helps hashing a key efficiently is not a problem, I have already implemented it so that it updates every time a move is made.

Comment: Perhaps a vector isn't the correct container type? Perhaps use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: or use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` if you want to find the values linked to the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vector whose size is a power of 2, and mask off the corresponding part of the Zobrist hash to get an index into the vector. For example:

```
std::vector<whatever> x(0x100000)
std::int64_t hash = get_hash_from_somewhere();
whatever& value = x[hash & 0xFFFFF];
```

You might want to use a more sophisticated mask if that one leads to too many collisions.

Comment: Thanks a TON. Btw I was wondering, do you know if this is how programs like stockfish use their transposition table?

Comment: I don't know how Stockfish does it. That's how I did it. <g>